# How to display strings containing a "\n" in Django HTML template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I can not find a way to use string variable containing a `\n` in Django HTML templates.
This is my template:

```
<body>
    <textarea id="my-text"></textarea>
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById("my-text").value = "{{ message }}";
</script>
```

with

```
message = "Message containing a \n character"
```

When Django renders the template, it generates an HTML like this one:

```
<body>
    <textarea id="my-text"></textarea>
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById("my-text").value = "Message containing a 
 character";
</script>
```

and the Javascript does not work.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using backtick in Javascript which allows to write a string on more lines. This is my new template:

```
<body>
    <textarea id="my-text"></textarea>
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById("my-text").value = `{{ message }}`;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Django filter `linebreaksbr` to convert the plain text into HTML format

```
{{ message|linebreaksbr }}
```

Comment: That would print a "<br>" in the textarea. I just solved using backticks in Javascript, thanks